# Radon transformation in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Here is a dummy code:

```
def radon(img):
    theta = np.linspace(-90., 90., 180, endpoint=False)
    sinogram = skimage.transform.radon(img, theta=theta, circle=True)
    return sinogram
# end def
```

I need to get the sinogram this code outputs without using `skimage`. But I am unable to find any implementation in python. Can you provide an implementation using only OpenCV, numpy or any other light-weight libraries?

**Edit**: I need this to get the dominating angle of the image. I am trying to fix the tilt before character segmentation for an OCR system. Examples are given below:

[image]

On the left side are the inputs, and on the right side are the desired output.

**Edit 2**: If you can provide any other ways to get this output, it will help too.

**Edit 3**: Some sample images:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2MwGW-_t275Q2Nxb3k3TGg4N1U

Comment: What are you trying to detect from the sinogram?

Comment: I need to get the dominating angle of the image. I am trying to fix the tilt before character segmentation for an OCR system

Comment: Post an image and a possible desired output.

Comment: Dude post the original images where we can test something on, not this resized/merged version.

Comment: I've added some sample images. let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I had a similar problem.. After spending some time googling the issue, I found a solution that worked for me. I hope it helps.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

from skimage.transform import radon


filename = 'your_filename'
# Load file, converting to grayscale
img = cv2.imread(filename)
I = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h, w = I.shape
# If the resolution is high, resize the image to reduce processing time.
if (w > 640):
    I = cv2.resize(I, (640, int((h / w) * 640)))
I = I - np.mean(I)  # Demean; make the brightness extend above and below zero
# Do the radon transform
sinogram = radon(I)
# Find the RMS value of each row and find "busiest" rotation,
# where the transform is lined up perfectly with the alternating dark
# text and white lines
r = np.array([np.sqrt(np.mean(np.abs(line) ** 2)) for line in sinogram.transpose()])
rotation = np.argmax(r)
print('Rotation: {:.2f} degrees'.format(90 - rotation))

# Rotate and save with the original resolution
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w/2, h/2), 90 - rotation, 1)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (w, h))
cv2.imwrite('rotated.jpg', dst)
```

**Test:**
Original image:
[image]

Rotated image: (rotation degree is -9°)
[image]

**CREDITS:**
[Detecting rotation and line spacing of image of page of text using Radon transform](https://gist.github.com/endolith/334196bac1cac45a4893#file-rotation_spacing-py)

The problem is that after rotating the image, you will get some black borders. For your case, I think it will not affect the OCR processing.